# What type to use for drizzle "where" statements for a Typescript library function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, orm, drizzle

I am trying to create a generic library function to replace all the drizzle instances where I use the same select and where statements in my repo.

I have a type for select, but cannot figure out the type for the where function. This is what I have so far:

```
type TransactionSelectFields = (typeof transactions)["_"]["columns"];
const getAllTransactions = async <P extends Partial<TransactionSelectFields>>(
  selectParams?: P,
  where?: ???
  limit = 10,
): Promise<DbTransaction[]> => {
  const transactionSchema = dbSchema.transactions;
  let getTransactions;
  if (selectParams) {
    getTransactions = db.select(selectParams);
  } else {
    // Fetches all columns if no select parameters
    getTransactions = db.select();
  }
  return await getTransactions.from(transactionSchema).limit(limit);
};
```

I've also looked at these docs on dynamic query building in drizzle which somewhat helped, but don't mention 'where' specifically: https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/dynamic-query-building